# Play Windows games on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: games, playonlinux

Currently I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I have tried installing Windows games with "PlayOnLinux" but all the games I tried to install it displays an error (it says that the program should be closed).
Please what can i do?.

Comment: I suggest searching first in askubuntu for this. It has been answer many times. Although you do not say which game you are trying to install or hardware that you have, most wine problems are solved either in the winehq forums, ubuntu forum or here so try to search first that you might find many useful questions that will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wine for games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8659/wine-for-games)

Answer (score 1):

Desura is a software that allows to play games on Ubuntu, but most games are not free. You can find [here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/download-and-play-games-on-ubuntu-with.html) installation instructions:

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem (Excel, not games) and finally installed [VMWare Player](https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/index.php). Just install the flavor of Windows you like and after that install the game you want to play.

Comment: I have used VirtualBox before using playonlinux but the games dosen't work on it

Answer (score 0):

one of possible solutions is to install wine.
for me it was my way to play Counter Strike 1.6 (Ubuntu 16.04)