# How to install Windows games on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, games

Would you please tell me how to install Windows games on Ubuntu? I really need it.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you to try [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) which is a wrapper for [wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

You can get an overview about [Gaming and Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games) in the wiki.

By the way, Valve is [currently working](http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/linux/beta-late-than-never-3/) on a Steam version for linux.

Answer (score 2):

must refer this first :-
[wine for games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8659/wine-for-games)

there are several software available for that "wine" is one of them, you should look at following links :-

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/wine

http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-wine-to-play-latest-windows-games-in-linux-ubuntu-linuxmint-fedora/

Answer (score 2):

To get the latest developement version of PlayOnLinux, open a terminal and type:

```
git clone https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4
```

alternatively you can do the following:-

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | apt-key add -
wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_squeeze.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then run the playonlinux
[image: Click on the Install button in this window]

Click on the Install button in the above window

[image]

Install the game and enjoy